# How can I clear active item in Vue v-list?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

In Vuetify's v-list-item directive I can't remove the active prop once an item has been selected. So far this is what I have tried:

```
      <v-list-item-group pb-6 color="primary" class="pb-3 text-left">
         <v-list-item v-for="(answer, index) in answers" :key="index">
            <v-list-item-title :class="{ active: isActive }" v-text="answer" @click.prevent="selectAnswer(index)">
            </v-list-item-title>
         </v-list-item>
      </v-list-item-group>

<b-button variant="primary" :disabled="hasAnswered" @click="submitAnswer()">
Submit
</b-button>
```

```
    export default {
  name: 'QuestionBox',
  data () {
    return {
      answers: '',
      selectedIndex: null,
      hasAnswered: false,
      isActive: undefined
    }
  },
  methods: {
    selectAnswer (ind) {
      this.isActive = true
      this.selectedIndex = ind
    },
    submitAnswer () {
      this.hasAnswered = true
      this.isActive = false
    }
  }
}
```

I know the `:class="{ active: isActive }"` will apply to the v-list-item-title, but the v-list-item has the v-for so anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that by using the `v-model`

Calling `clear` method from examples will clear the selection

### Example (single selection):

```html
<v-list-item-group v-model="selection">
```

```js
data: () => ({
  selection: null
}),
methods:{
  clear(){ this.selection = null }
}
```

### Example (multiple selections):

```html
<v-list-item-group v-model="selection" multiple>
```

```js
data:() => ({
  selection: []
}),
methods:{
  clear(){ this.selection = [] }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, can you also point me into why a v-model is able to solve this?

Comment: Model represents the selection with 2-way binding. So if you update the model, the selection changes.